# What is % in Lua [not for numeric operations]?

Tags: string, lua

So I was using string.find() to find "(" in my string. But without "%" before "(" (like "%(") it says: "unfinished capture". What exactly this symbol doing?

Works:

```
local str = "(text)"
print(str:find("%("))
```

Don`t work:

```
local str = "(text)"
print(str:find("("))
```

Comment: Side note: You could use the fourth parameter to `string.find` ("raw") to specify that you do not want to search for a pattern, but rather a raw search string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used in [patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html), used in [some functions](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) related to finding. For example, `%s` means "find a single whitespace character". `%(` searches for the character `(`. The reason you can't directly write `(` is that that will create a [capture](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html), which is a mechanism to retrieve a part of a match. For other characters, you directly type them, unless there is a similar restriction.